# Scala: extract each value for each key in a Map using for loop

Tags: scala, dictionary, for-loop

I am trying to extract the values from the keys `v1` and `v2`.

I would like it to print like this

*first the v1*

- 900
- 1800

*and then v2*

- 700
- 800
- 2600
- 1800
- 2100

This is how far I have done but I get an error in my second for loop that I do not know how to solve. Is this write scala approach to solve this or is there a better way?

```
     val some_numbers = Map("v1"->(900, 1800),
                            "v2"->(700, 800, 2600, 1800, 2100))
     
     for ((key,values) <-some_numbers) {
       for(value<-values)
         print(value)
     }
```

Comment: Like this: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/BalmungSan/7e0qTtAaRAq2G8TFrGjlGg ?

Comment: It is very very unlikely that you really want to have a map with tuple values of different sizes. See the type of the map, it will be `Map[String, Product]`, quite useless. You probably misunderstand the usage of tuples here.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot iterate directly on a tuple value.

I do not know what is your application need. BTW you can iterate on tuple using `productIterator`:

```
 for ((key,values) <-some_numbers) {
   for(value<-values.productIterator) {
     println(value)
   }
 }
```

This should work. But probably it is better to use List instead of tuple in this case!